# Dealing with ThinkingSphinx realtime indices when destroying records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to convert a delta-based index in ThinkingSphinx into a realtime one. Per the docs, I've added this callback:

`after_save ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:location)`

That works just fine for adding and updating records, woo. My problem is in deleting records, which according to the Rails docs, don't trigger `after_save` callbacks. I've confirmed this by deleting a record, which is not then deleted from my sphinx index.

I tried

`after_destroy ThinkingSphinx::RealTime.callback_for(:location)`

But this raises an error (as the realtime callbacks do not support `after_destroy`).

How can I remove an entry from my index when using a real time index?

(`thinking-sphinx 3.3.0`, `rails 5.0.4`, if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx automatically adds its own `after_destroy` callback to all indexed models, so removal of these records from real-time indices should happen without you needing to add any code.

Comment: Thanks Pat (glad to see you monitor this tag). Is the `after_save` callback necessary then, or is that added automatically as well?

Comment: The after_save is not called automatically, so you definitely need to keep it in your code. Perhaps if I had my time again, the after_destroy would not be either (taking the more explicit route rather than invading an app's code more recklessly).

Comment: It doesn't look like the docs have a repo I can pull against, but even a note in the docs would have gone a long way. My development log notably doesn't show the Sphinx query when I do the destroy.

Comment: Just added a note in the docs (which are in the `gh-pages` branch of the repo - not entirely obvious, I'm well aware). Also, added a commit so these delete statements to Sphinx show up in the Rails logs: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/commit/6b809c6f9db85022f930d03cf12c2992dd42a565

Comment: Thanks for that, Pat!

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need to do this manually, for example when soft-deleting objects.

```rb
ThinkingSphinx::ActiveRecord::Callbacks::DeleteCallbacks.after_destroy(instance)
```

Reference: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/1057